# At least one object must implement IComparable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, dynamic-linq

Model:

```
return (from m in meterReadings
       group m by new { date = m.ReadDate } into g
       select new
       {
           ReadDate = g.Key.date.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - HH:mm:ss"),
           T1 = from t1 in g
                where t1.Name == "T1"
                select t1.Value.ToString("0,0.000"),
           T2 = from t2 in g
                where t2.Name == "T2"
                select t2.Value.ToString("0,0.000"),
           T3 = from t3 in g
                where t3.Name == "T3"
                select t3.Value.ToString("0,0.000"),
           Total = from total in g
                where total.Name == "Toplam"
                select total.Value.ToString("0,0.000")
       }).AsQueryable<object>();
```

Query

```
var table = MeterReadingManager.GetMeterReadingsPivot(meterReadings, 1);
//No Error (in title)
rows = table.OrderBy("ReadDate","desc").Skip((pageIndex) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
//Error  (in title)
rows = table.OrderBy("T1","desc").Skip((pageIndex) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
```

When I order by ReadDate, It works. But When I try to order by other fields I get the error : `At least one object must implement IComparable`

Why I get this error? And How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sort a list of items of any type, the type must implement `IComparable` for the sort algorithm to be able to compare items. `T1` is an `IQueryable`, whcih does not implement `IComparable`. I think you intended to create string values for T1, T2, and T3. If so, you should add `FirstOrDefault()` to each linq statement creating T1, etc.

**Edit**

(After your comment)

I mean this:

```cs
T1 = (from t1 in g
     where t1.Name == "T1"
     select t1.Value.ToString("0,0.000")).FirstOrDefault()
```

Now `T1` is a string and, thus, it can be used in sorting.

Comment: Yes. Your suggestion works. But I cant understant fully. Especially in the last sentence. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `ThenByDescending`:

```
var rows = table
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.ReadDate).Skip((pageIndex) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.T1).Skip((pageIndex) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

**UPDATE**:
You could use Reflection (a bit slower) if ordering by one field:

```
var tableInfo = table.GetType().GetProperty("T1"); 
var sortedRow = table.OrderByDescending(x => tableInfo.GetValue(x, null)).Skip((pageIndex) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

Comment: I want to order by only one field. Also, with dynamic linq expression.

Comment: sorry, but I want to try dynamic query. Thanks for reply.